# ecognition- template matching result export

Tags: coordinate-system, ecognition

I am doing template matching for tree detection purpose using ecognition software. When I export the point layer result from ecognition into QGIS using the 'export the existing vector layer function',  QGIS couldn't recognize the CRS of the vector layer (different in size and coordinates) and I need to use transformation to put them into correct place but it's not really accurate.

Can anyone help me with this issue?